# Is there a VS Code Shortcut for search bar in keyboard preferences?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I use the key chord <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> shortcut to get to the keyboard shortcut preferences but once I'm there, how can I put my cursor on the search bar.  I'm not talking about the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> search but this one:
[image]

Comment: It does that automatically for me.  Where is your focus when you CTRL+K, CTRL+S ?

Comment: It does the first time but if you move the cursor (say, update an entry) then subsequent visits to that editor/buffer will put you back to wherever you were last time.